# UIWebView how to check if connected to Internet

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiwebview, ios8, nsurl

I am using xCode 6. I am using a UIWebView. It is connecting to a link through NSURL. How do I make an error message that happens when the user is not connected to WiFi or internet? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I found a solution. In the .h file put a  after the @interface, then in the .m file call a method in viewDidLoad that is webview.delegate=self.